# Packaging Kivy into exe file (without command)

Tags: python, windows, exe, kivy, packaging

How can I package my python **Kivy** project into an executable **exe** file, **without** using commands explained in https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html page.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use any of the python executable packagers, such as nuitka or cx_freeze. We suggest (and give instructions for) pyinstaller because we've found it the most flexible and practical, though. Note that packaging Kivy involves extra steps beyond simple python scripts because of the compilation and external dependencies, there is no way to avoid this.